# Свой js в ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Есть проект на `ionic`, самое обычное приложение. И мне не хватает функционала предоставляемого мне этим фреймворком, могу ли я создать, например, обычный `.js`файл там прописать код и использовать его в проекте, но так, чтобы этот скрипт был рабочим и после того как соберу проект в `.apk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, вы можете использовать JS в Ionic.
Но вы должны его подключить. Есть несколько способов:

1. Через index.html как обычный JS файл.
2. В Angular.json в свойстве `scripts`.

Но по-моему, если вы будете использовать в компоненте свой JS, то его нужно добавить через `import`. Например:

```
import * as myscript from {path-to-script}
```

P.S Это если используете Angular.